# Setting up a mail server to send mail from IP

Tags: 12.04, mail-server, ip

I have a fixed LAN IP, but no domain name. I'd like to be able to send emails within the LAN, and receive mails sent to my IP (user needs to send an email to username@10.xx.xx.xx). I've tried the stuff in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/a/55027/69210) -- the "easy" one gives me an IMAP error in squirrelmail (IMAP is open and listening, but not working), and the "hard" one seems to be outdated.

Is it possible to set up an email server (preferably on 12.04) without having a domain name?

Answer (score 2):

You can use gmail as relay.

**Ubuntu postfix. Using gmail as SMTP relay**

Gmail as SMTP-service.

Install postfix.

```
sudo apt-get install postfix
```

Select the settings during installation according to your needs.

If you ever need to redo the configuration run:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure postfix
```

Edit /etc/postfix/main.cf by adding the following rows:

```
relayhost = smtp.gmail.com:587

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes

smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous

smtp_use_tls = yes
```

Create the file /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd with the following content:

**smtp.gmail.com:587 your_account@gmail.com:password**

When done run and restart postfix afterwards:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd

sudo service postfix restart
```

http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/20535-ubuntu-postfix-using-gmail-as-smtp-relay

Comment: Yes, but then Gmail won't let me send the mail as xyz@ipaddress. Gmail's SMTP removes header spoofing, so this won't work. I'd like full control on the email being sent.